# Constructing a graph from a degree sequence

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let's say I'm given several degree sequences like

$$\begin{array}{l}
\{4,3,3,2,2\} \\
\{3,3,3,3\} \\
\{5,3,3,2,2,1\}
\end{array}$$
I can find the number of edges using the handshaking lemma
$$
\sum_{v \in V} \operatorname{deg}(v)=2|E|
$$

But how do I construct a graph just given these degree sequences? There are multiple types of graphs that satisfy the degree sequences, but beyond guess & checking, is there a logic/pattern to follow when making graphs? Right now I'm at the guess & check stage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have some requirements like planarity or connectedness, then you are left with trial and error. However, if you would like any simple graph with the given degree sequence, then you can do a simple algorithm:

- Sort the degrees descending.
- Connect the highest degree $d$ to the next $d$ vertices, e.g. $$(4,3,2,1,1,1) \leadsto (3-1,2-1,1-1,1-1,1) = (2,1,1).$$
- Iterate until finished.

The idea behind it is rather simple, if you want the full proof, then you can find it [here](https://eudml.org/doc/19050) (Václav Havel, 1955, non-English). Some info is also available at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I still don't get it. Connect the highest degree d to the next d vertices.  So I have a dot that is connected to 4 other dots, and subtract 4 degrees of freedom from the 4 connected dots. In the case above, that leaves (2,1,1) more connections. Now what dot do I choose? I have a fan-like thing of dots.

Comment: @Luke You again sort degrees descending, take the highest, i.e. d=2, and connect to the $d$ others, namely the two 1s.

Comment: its probably too late to ask but how would this arrange a sequence like 2,2,2,2,2?It will fail.Did i miss something?

Comment: @rahulsharma $$(2,2,2,2,2)⇝(2-1,2-1,2,2)=(2,2,1,1)⇝(2-1,1-1,1)=(1,1)⇝()$$

Comment: ahh. we need sorted entries after every iteration.I did sorting only once.Thanks:)