# Algorithmically constructing graphs with specified degrees

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In graph theory books there are lots of problems similar to these:

- Construct a graph of 7 vertices with exactly 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 degrees
- Prove or disprove that there is graph of 4 vertices with exactly 3, 2, 2, 1 degrees

By algorithmical construction of such graphs I mean constructing them from an empty graph with repeatedly adding edges, following a rule.

Of course, in many cases, such graph does not even exists. For example, if the sum of the degrees is not even.

The goal is finding a single graph, so there is only one way to draw to first edge, since isomorphic graphs are equivalent in this context. (They all solve the same problems). So the first step is trivial. The next step has two possible options: connecting two isolated vertices, or extending the new component that the first step made. There is always either at least a single possible step that does not make any degree to high, or we need to "undo" some steps. If the order of the sequence of these steps does matter, all these possible steps form a directed tree, in which each vertex represents a possible sequence. If we chose a "bad step", we can "go back", and try the sibling vertices (step sequences). If one of them construct a correct graph, then we're done, else the parent node itself is "bad", so we can repeat this step. So, if such graph exists, I think this algorithm will find that in finite steps. Also, if such graph does not exist, this proves it. If the output graph must be a simple graph, then there are finite number of possible steps. If the output can be non-simple graph, then the directed tree of possible step sequences is infinite, but all possible walks from the starting vertex bump into either a "bad" vertex, or a solution, because any possible way of adding loops or parallel edges will make a too high degree vertex in finite steps.

So if I'm right, this bruteforce algorithm works (does it?), but is there a better algorithm which does not have the potential to unnecessarily require to try so many bad steps?

Comment: Look up "Havel-Hakimi algorithm".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527530/constructing-a-graph-from-a-degree-sequence

Comment: By the way, the (3,2,2,1) graph is the paw.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PawGraph.html