# Graph Isomorphism degrees

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Can someone please explain this to me and how to approach the problem? I don't have any work done because I have no idea what graphic is #1, and number 2 I don't really understand the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read about what is a graphic sequence at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence).

To prove some sequence *is* graphic, it's best to provide an example of a graph with such a sequence of degrees.

To prove something is *not* a graphic sequence, you could use the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem), but it's easier to follow the construction of Havel, which I sketched [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/527714/26306). If you can't construct a graph with such a sequence of degrees, then it's not graphic.

However, in your particular case I can give you the following hints:

- $\deg(v) < n$ for any $v \in V$,
- $\Big|\big\{ v \mid \deg(v) = n-1 \big\}\Big| \leq \min_{v \in V} \deg(v)$,

for a simple graph, where $n = |V|$. With some work it should be enough to prove both cases.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$