# Determining whether a given set of vertices form a simple graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to determine if vertices with degrees 0,1,1,2 can form a simple graph.

The Handshaking Theorem holds, however, I am not sure if two connected vertices, a vertex with a loop, and a disconnected vertex on its own can represent this graph.

Does a simple graph allow for loops?

I also tried: 
a1,a2,…,an the degrees of vertex 1

∑ki=1ai≤k(k−1)+∑ni=k+1min{k,ai}.

holds as well.

Comment: Simple graphs don't have loops. For constructing a graph with given degree sequence see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/527714/26306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple graphs don't have loops.

But there is a simple graph with these degrees. And you can just draw it. Here's a particularly simple way of notating it:

$$ \wedge \quad .$$

(notice the .)